# PostgreSQL function thinks table reference exists when it does not

Tags: postgresql, database-design, plpgsql, catalogs

So I run this query:

```
SELECT f_copy_tbl('parts','parts1');
```

...while working on code based off of [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91632/copy-table-with-separate-seuquences-for-serial-columns#answer-91658) and I get this error message:

> ERROR:  relation "parts1" already exists

pgAdmin III doesn't show the table (and I obviously reloaded the left column pressing F5 after clicking on the correct items because it's of cascading reload effect). Just to cover my bases I run the following query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parts1 RESTRICT;
```

...to which psql returns:

> NOTICE:  table "parts1" does not exist, skipping

So *what* is `parts1` a reference to if not a table?

How many queries? All the queries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_copy_tbl(_tbl regclass, _newtbl text)
 RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

-- Copy table
EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I (LIKE %s INCLUDING ALL);', _newtbl, _tbl);

-- Fix serial columns, if any
EXECUTE (
SELECT concat_ws(E'\n'
       , string_agg('CREATE SEQUENCE ' || seq, E';\n') || ';'
       , string_agg(format('ALTER SEQUENCE %s OWNED BY %I.%I;'
                          , seq, _newtbl, a.attname), E'\n')
       , 'ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(_newtbl)
       , string_agg(format($$ALTER %I SET DEFAULT nextval('%s'::regclass)$$
                                 , a.attname, seq), E',\n')
       )
FROM   pg_attribute  a
JOIN   pg_attrdef    ad ON ad.adrelid = a.attrelid
                       AND ad.adnum   = a.attnum
     , quote_ident(_newtbl || '_' || a.attname || '_seq') AS seq  -- new seq name
WHERE  a.attrelid = _tbl
AND    a.attnum > 0
AND    NOT a.attisdropped
AND    a.atttypid = ANY ('{int,int8,int2}'::regtype[])
AND    ad.adsrc = 'nextval('''
         || (pg_get_serial_sequence (a.attrelid::regclass::text, a.attname))::regclass
         || '''::regclass)'
);

--Now populate `parts1` table with `parts` table's content...
SELECT f_copy_tbl('parts','parts1');
INSERT INTO parts1 SELECT * FROM parts;

--Now get primary key so we can fix the sequence...
--DECLARE PKEY VARCHAR;
--SELECT pg_attribute.attname INTO PKEY FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute WHERE pg_class.oid = 'parts1'::regclass AND indrelid = pg_class.oid AND pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid AND pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey) AND indisprimary;

--Now 
--SELECT setval('parts1_' || INTO PKEY || '_seq', (SELECT MAX(pkey) + 1 FROM parts));


/**********
--Now get highest number of primary key *AND* increment it...
--DECLARE PKEY_NUMBER INTEGER;
--SELECT (PKEY + 1) INTO PKEY_NUMBER FROM parts1 ORDER BY PKEY DESC LIMIT 1;

--Fix primary key's autoincrement...
--ALTER SEQUENCE parts1_id_seq RESTART WITH PKEY_NUMBER;
*********/

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Note that this is based on an **outdated** version of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91632/copy-table-with-separate-seuquences-for-serial-columns/91658#91658

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you have defined a recursive function ... the function is calling itself.  The logic that exists in it currently would result in a stack dump with OUT OF MEMORY error (or something along those lines, at least) if it didn't give you the error of "table already exists" to begin with..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_copy_tbl(_tbl regclass, _newtbl text)
 RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN

--<snip stuff>

--Now populate `parts1` table with `parts` table's content...
SELECT f_copy_tbl('parts','parts1');  --- THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE HERE .. REMOVE IT
INSERT INTO parts1 SELECT * FROM parts;

--<snip stuff>

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Your order of SQL should be as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(param1 VARCHAR, param2 VARCHAR) RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
  var1 VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  -- DO STUFFS HERE FOR FUNCTION
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
-- THE ABOVE DEFINES THE FUNCTION

-- THE BELOW EXECUTES THE FUNCTION
SELECT my_func('val1', 'val2'); -- THIS ONE LINE WILL EXECUTE ALL SQL DEFINED INSIDE THE FUNCTION
```

The function definition is what is between the dollar quoting..