# Reset the sequence of a serial PK with dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, auto-increment

How can I dynamically reference a sequence name (as below) using a combination of strings and `DECLARE` variables? Is the code below proper or is there another method of doing this?

My goal is to do this within a `DO`/`BEGIN` block for performance reasons plus it'll help me understand plpgsql by doing something useful so I'm not going to mix this in to PHP unless I really have to.

```
DO $$
 DECLARE PKEY VARCHAR;
BEGIN

SELECT pg_attribute.attname INTO PKEY 
FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute 
WHERE pg_class.oid = 'parts1'::regclass 
AND indrelid = pg_class.oid 
AND pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid 
AND pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey) 
AND indisprimary;

--SELECT setval('parts1_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(pkey) + 1 FROM parts));
SELECT setval('parts1_' || PKEY || '_seq', (SELECT MAX(pkey) + 1 FROM parts));

  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### General advice

You mentioned it yourself, you just started using Postgres. Yet, you're tackling **extremely advanced tasks** right away, juggling system catalogs and operating with advanced dynamic SQL to automate things.

While your objectives seem reasonable, you still need to **start at the basics**. *There is just too much to explain here.* Start with (relevant parts of) [the excellent manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/). I provided a couple of deep links further down.

### Answer

To get name(s) (and data type(s)) of columns involved in the primary key, rather use this simpler query:

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_index i
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                     AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
WHERE  i.indrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
AND    i.indisprimary;
```

I updated the [Postgres Wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns) where your original query seems to originate from.

**However**, this can return multiple rows, while you only assign a single value. Assuming you have **established** that we are dealing with a `serial` type (single column) primary key. Else use similar techniques as laid out in my [previous answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91632/copy-table-with-separate-sequences-for-serial-columns/91658#91658) to make sure.

Then use the dedicated system information function **`pg_get_serial_sequence()`** to determine the name of the used sequence, like [demonstrated in my previous answer](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns).
[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html)

> get name of the sequence that a `serial`, `smallserial` or `bigserial` column uses

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
   SELECT format($$SELECT setval('%s'::regclass, max(%I)) FROM %s$$
                 , pg_get_serial_sequence(a.attrelid::regclass::text, a.attname)
                 , a.attname
                 , a.attrelid::regclass
                )
   FROM   pg_index i
   JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                        AND a.attnum = i.indkey[0]
   WHERE  i.indrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
   AND    i.indisprimary
   );
END
$do$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This builds and executes a query of the form:

```
SELECT setval('tbl_tbl_id_seq'::regclass, max(tbl_id)) FROM tbl;
```

#### Explain / Advise

- This is **advanced stuff** and not really suitable for beginners. Messing with system catalogs can go south quickly if you don't know exactly what you are doing.
- Stick to legal all-lower case identifiers in Postgres and plpgsql to make your life easier. But **never** rely on it in dynamic SQL, where you also need to defend against SQL injection at all times.
- Making heavy use of [**`format()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to build the query string conveniently & safely.
- Inside a plpgsql function you cannot call `SELECT` without assigning the result. You would use `PERFORM` instead. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT)
  I removed that completely, since I reduced everything to a single `EXECUTE`.
- Since the whole operation only makes sense for a single-column  primary key, I simplified the `JOIN` condition to `a.attnum = i.indkey[0]`
  Note that `pg_index.indkey` has the special (internal) type `int2vector`. Unlike Postgres arrays its index starts with **0**, not 1.
- Make it a habbit to use dollar-quotes with a token around plpgsql code (including `DO` statements). This allows to nest simple dollar-quotes like I do in my example. Details:

  - [Insert varchar with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)
- You only need a single `SELECT` here:

  ```
  SELECT setval('tbl_tbl_id_seq'::regclass, max(tbl_id)) FROM tbl;
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  SELECT setval('tbl_tbl_id_seq'::regclass, (SELECT max(tbl_id) FROM tbl));
  ```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c90f3/2) demonstrating a few things.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you have a SQL statement that it dynamic in nature (can potentially change at runtime) that you need to run inside of a function, you need to run `EXECUTE` for it.

[See Section 40.5.4. Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html)

You need to be aware that executing SQL this way CAN be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Your line above:

```
SELECT setval('parts1_' || INTO PKEY || '_seq', (SELECT MAX(pkey) + 1 FROM parts));
```

Would become (at least, I believe this is the intent)

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT setval(''parts1_' || PKEY || '_seq'', (SELECT MAX(' || pkey || ') + 1 FROM parts))';
```

- Note .. the doubled single quote (`''`) inside a string is treated as a literal single quote (like \')
- Note 2 .. to protect against SQL Injection, you can EXECUTE a formatted string (as Erwin Brandstetter has already supplied several examples to you in a different post)