# Advance primary key after mass insert

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

I have a table with a few rows in it. It has a primary. I insert a large number of rows, including all fields including the primary key. Now when I try to an insert without specifying the primary key it fails because it's trying to use a number that was already used as a primary key in the previously inserted rows. How can I tell the table to create new primary keys at numbers higher than the existing keys?

For example, say I have rows with primary keys 1-8 in the table and I do a mass insert of rows with primary keys 9 through 64. Then I try to do a single insert without a primary key and it fails because it's trying to use 9. The next try fails because it's trying to use 10. And so on. I want to tell the table to start counting new primary keys at 65. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tbl', 'tbl_id'), max(tbl_id)) FROM tbl;
```

Table name and column name are two separate parameters to the [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) function.
And you don't need a subselect.
Details:

- [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23390399/939860)
- [Reset the sequence of a serial PK with dynamic SQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91731/reset-the-sequence-of-a-serial-pk-with-dynamic-sql/91763#91763)